# Colored text in a dcolumn table

Tags: tables, color, dcolumn

I want to highlight text in a table using my own color definitions. The table is a `dcolumn` table. It doesn't work, I get the error messages `! Missing } inserted.` and `! Extra }, or forgotten $.` three times.

Below is a min example for the `beamer` class (I did not check out other classes).

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{default}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\usepackage{booktabs, dcolumn}
# Now I create my own color to highlight text
\definecolor{red4}{rgb}{0.545,0.000,0.000}
\newcommand{\mcdr}[1]{{{\bf \color{red4}#1}}}

\begin{document}
#-----------
\begin{frame}

\begin{table}
  \begin{tabular}{p{1cm} D{.}{.}{3.5}@{} }
    \toprule
    average & {\mcdr{-0.01}}     \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{frame}
#-----------
\end{document}
```

However, embedding `\mcdr` in a normal table, everything works fine:

```
  \begin{center}
   \begin{tabular}{l | l }
     early& {\mcdr{0.1}}  \tabularnewline
     late& \textit{0.11} \tabularnewline
   \end{tabular}
  \end{center}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! When posting some code, please do check that it's free of syntax errors, such as stating `\bein{table}` and using `#` instead of `%` as the comment symbol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

D column type is consist from two (sub)columns. For example, if you put \color{red4} before number -0,01 you will see, that only first part of number (-1) become red4 colored. Closing this number in any macro hide "." which is separator between (sub) columns.

The solution close to this what you (as I understand) like can be:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{default}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\usepackage{booktabs, dcolumn}
% Now I create my own color to highlight text
\definecolor{red4}{rgb}{0.545,0.000,0.000}
\newcommand{\mcdr}[1]{{{\bf \color{red4}#1}}}
    \newcolumntype{F}[3]{>{\color{red4}\DC@{#1}{#2}{#3}}c<{\DC@end}}
    \newcolumntype{d}[1]{F{.}{.}{#1}}

\begin{document}
%-----------
\begin{frame}

\begin{table}
  \begin{tabular}{p{1cm} D{.}{.}{3.5}@{} }
    \toprule
    average & \mcdr{-0}.\mcdr{01}     \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{frame}
%-----------
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The `-` has the spacing of a binary (not unary) operator. Rather use `{-}`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of loading the `dcolumn` package and its `D` column type, I recommend (for this application at least) loading the `siunitx` package and using its `S` column type. Separately, I think you should eiter use color or bold, but not both simultaneously; I'd go for color to highlight items in a `beamer` document.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor, booktabs, siunitx}
% Now I create my own color to highlight text
\definecolor{red4}{rgb}{0.545,0.000,0.000}
\newcommand{\mcdr}{\color{red4}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{table}
  \begin{tabular}{p{1.5cm} 
                  S[table-format=3.5, group-digits=false] 
                  @{} }
    \toprule
    average    & \mcdr -0.01      \\
    difference & \mcdr -12.34567  \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This seems to be a very good package. Only, I cannot change because my tables come from the `R` package `stargazer()`.

Comment: @MERose - It's important to mention this when you posted the query.

Comment: ...in which case I would not have learned of `siunitx`!